# jquery to customize back button

Tags: jquery

I have a page in tridion with 3 tabs, each containing two more tabs "`gridview`" and "`detailsview`". These 3 tabs are also individual pages. When user is in any of the tabs and viewing either "`grid`" or "`details`" and clicks the "`back`" button in the browser, the user is taken to the previous tab, and that means another page. Is there any way to make the user to remain on the same page and toggle within the "`grid`" or "`detailsview`" when they click the browser "`back`" button?

Comment: This quesiton way too complex to build up from scratch. Especially without prodividing any code.

Comment: does my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Tools has a solution for this: http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/one-sized.html

the script is here: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/scrollable/scrollable.navigator.js

it should be able to be adapted for your use.